# Scaling TextBox to the text within

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to make a TextBox surrounded with a glowing border.

The TextBox should be as large as it needs to be in order to contain all the text within. But no larger. And the Border should then surround the text.

I use a 3x3 Grid to make the Border centered in the middle of the container. Centering works fine as long as the text is short enough. But when you enter a big long text, the ViewBox will not actually scale the TextBox down in size.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Border BorderBrush="#bab98b" BorderThickness="7" CornerRadius="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
            <TextBox Name="WaitMessage" Text="A Message" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="Black" Padding="20" FontSize="60" Width="Auto"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

I thought the Viewbox was supposed to scale the content to fit within the dimensions available according to the parent container. But what happens is that if I enter a text that is very long, it will clip at the end.

In short: I want the text to uniformly shrink to available size, but never grow beyond what's needed.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Ok, If I Put in 10* as Width and Height of the middle column and row the text will always stay inside the border. 
The problem is then that the ViewBox will make the text grow, when it's only a small text.
I can't use maxHeight for this purpose I think, because I just never want it to enlarge the text.

Comment: Have you tried TextBox wrapping ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything. Also, it doesn't explain why the Viewbox won't shrink the TextBox IMO.

Comment: Please, rewrite your question and try to make it simpler and understandable by puting your actual code and what you exactly expect from it

Comment: I wanted to be able to scale the text in case it wouldn't fit. For that I wanted to use the ViewBox. But you were right about the TextWrapping. It was useful. I just found it it doesn't seem to work if you put it in a grid cell that has Width="Auto". But it works if I change the Width to a relative size (10* for example). So thank you, it was useful after fiddling with it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Viewbox.StretchDirection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretchdirection.aspx). [`StretchDirection.DownOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection.aspx) will do what you want.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
        <TextBox Text="A Message" FontSize="60" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how extensible this will be for the rest of your code, but to get the text in the center of the control you can do the following:

```
<Grid>
      <Border BorderBrush="#bab98b" BorderThickness="7" CornerRadius="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
          <TextBox Name="WaitMessage" Text="A Message" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="Black" Padding="20" FontSize="60" Width="Auto"/>
      </Border>
</Grid>
```